# Can I clone my Raspberry Pi 3b+ micro sd with Retropie and put it in a Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, retropie

If I clone my Raspberry Pi 3B+ SD card, which is set up with Retropie and heaps of ROM's on it, will it work if I put it in a Raspberry Pi 4?

I want to give a Retropie (3B+ or 4) to someone as a gift.

Should I just buy them a 3B+, since it is the exact same model as mine, since I know it will run flawlessly?

Or should I get a 4?

Comment: I just read on another thread that this might not be possible. But I can't figure out how to delete this question! Sorry about that!

Comment: You might instead want to include a link to that "other thread" since, while I'm not a retropie user, I don't see why this would not work -- generally speaking, you should be able to take a card from a 3 and put it into a 4 without too much pain ensuing.

Comment: There should be a `Delete` item just below the tags listed below your question.

Comment: here are the threads from the retropie reddit group: https://www.reddit.com/r/RetroPie/comments/d6vflx/do_retropie_rom_collection_images_made_for_3b/      https://www.reddit.com/r/RetroPie/comments/j8k8an/will_an_image_build_to_an_older_pi_3b_work_on_the/      https://www.reddit.com/r/RetroPie/comments/kunpzi/will_a_pi_4_image_work_on_my_pi_3b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retropie has separate images for Pi3 and Pi4 so I don't believe cloning a Pi3 image to a Pi4 will work.

https://retropie.org.uk/download/

Comment: So if I go with the Pi4, is it as easy as 1. downloading the new Pi4 image, 2. flashing it to a micro sd card, then 3. configuring controllers, and 4. loading the rom's? (I'm a bit of a novice!) Will I have to install the emulators also? When loading the ROMs, how do I read the retropie micro sd card on my windows machine?

Comment: Yes, it’s all documented on the retropie site. https://retropie.org.uk/docs/First-Installation/ Please mark the answer.

Comment: I clicked the green tick. Is that marking the answer?